# docker-compose dynamic volume names for replicas

Tags: docker-compose

Tried some of the "solutions" from various threads and incl. stackoverflow and moby issues. No swarm, node or other hosts at all. Just trying to get it to work locally first without starting containers around docker-compose. Main idea is to get rid of these copies and just use replicas:

```yaml
  configsvr0:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configsvr --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --keyFile /data/keyfile
    volumes:
      - configsvr0:/data/db
      - ./keyfile:/data/keyfile:ro
  configsvr1:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configsvr --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --keyFile /data/keyfile
    volumes:
      - configsvr1:/data/db
      - ./keyfile:/data/keyfile:ro
  configsvr2:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configsvr --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --keyFile /data/keyfile
    volumes:
      - configsvr2:/data/db
      - ./keyfile:/data/keyfile:ro

volumes:
  configsvr0:
  configsvr1:
  configsvr2:
```

See the difference? It's just counting up on the volume name...

It would be great to just have something like this:

```yaml
  configsvr0:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet configsvr --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --keyFile /data/keyfile
    volumes:
      - configsvr:/data/db
      - ./keyfile:/data/keyfile:ro

volumes:
  configsvr:
    name: 'configsvr-{{.Task.Slot}}'
```

Tried this (see below) but it didn't work.

Note: Below I only copied small junks from my yml that I thought are important for this.

#### test 1 - volume name

would require to add entries under volumes so that's not really dynamic - but I gave it a try:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - "configsvr{{.Task.Slot}}:/data/db"
```

```
➜  msc git:(develop) ✗ docker-compose up configsvr0
service "configsvr0" refers to undefined volume configsvr{{.Task.Slot}}: invalid compose project
```

#### test2 - dynamic name with task slot

that would be dynamic but still doesn't work though it was accepted in stackoverflow. That's actually my sample from top.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - configsvr:/data/db

volumes:
  configsvr:
    name: 'configsvr-{{.Task.Slot}}'
```

```
➜  msc git:(develop) ✗ docker-compose up configsvr0
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠿ Volume "configsvr-{{.Task.Slot}}"  Error                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
Error response from daemon: create configsvr-{{.Task.Slot}}: "configsvr-{{.Task.Slot}}" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

#### my env

mac monteray with docker desktop.

```
➜  msc git:(develop) ✗ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
➜  msc git:(develop) ✗ docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.2.1

docker-compose.yml version: 3.9
```

also posted under https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9026

Comment: .Task.Slot is only expanded in swarm mode. It would work for the volume on the task, but I don't think it would work for the outer volume key. Because those are go template snippets, and I guess each snippet get as context the task it's being used on.